# backward difference encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding

[This tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/categorical-data) discussed the information about BackWard difference encoding:

> 5. Backward Difference Encoding
>
> This technique falls under the contrast coding system for categorical features. A feature of K categories, or levels, usually enters a regression as a sequence of K-1 dummy variables. In backward difference coding, the mean of the dependent variable for a level is compared with the mean of the dependent variable for the prior level. This type of coding may be useful for a nominal or an ordinal variable.
>
> If you want to learn other contrast coding methods you can check out this resource.
>
> The code structure is pretty much the same as any method in the category_encoders library, just this time you will call BackwardDifferenceEncoder from it

as it said, it will transform k categories into k-1 binary categories.

I used this method on its database. For 'carriers', we had 11 categories and what we received after encoding is also 11 categories. Isn't it supposed to be 10 categories or 10 columns of binary values?

```
df_flights = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismayc/pnwflights14/master/data/flights.csv')

df_flights.head()

df_flights['carrier'].unique()
```

so we have 11 unique categories.

```
!pip install category_encoders
import category_encoders as ce
cat_df_flights = df_flights.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
encoder = ce.BackwardDifferenceEncoder(cols=['carrier'])
df_bd = encoder.fit_transform(cat_df_flights)

df_bd.head()
```

the outcome is also 11 columns of binary data but based on what this tutorial said, it should be 10...

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure but probably it's because you can infer the remaining class. For instance, imagine you have two colors `{red, blue}` and you want encode that variable. One option is to create two columns, one for red and other for blue, but you could also create just `n - 1` columns for example "red"; if the value is 1 then the sample is red otherwise is blue.

Comment: I understand what you said. So why are there 11 dummy categories? it should be 10

Answer (score 0):

If you review the output of the encoding, you are correct that there are 11 columns. However, only 10 of these columns contain new information that is based on a comparison between the categories in the carrier column. The 11th column, "intercept", is simply a series of 1s and will have no impact on your modelling.

As to why this 11th column exists, I'm not completely sure. Following the logic of the backward difference encoding table, perhaps it could be viewed as comparing the uppermost level with the next level up. Given that every value in the column is belongs to the uppermost level or below, all values for the encoded column in this comparison will be 1 (and the other values, if they existed, would be 0).